# Sql Image column conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to convert an image column to a tif file. I understand the code and how it works but the column contents aren't making much sense to me.

I am hoping someone may recognize the contents and give me an idea how to proceed.

I pull the image column from my database and stuffed into into a byte array.

then created a filestream object and wrote out tif files (i kept getting invalid parameter when i used the memory stream method)

The filestream created the tif files but they could not be opened (message saying the file was corrupted.

So on a whim, i tried converting it to a string.

i suspect this is correct because the contents are now readable

```
"\0\u0001\0\0\0ÿÿÿÿ\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\u0002\0\0\0ISystem, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\u0005\u0001\0\0\0-System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary\u0004\0\0\0\u0004head\aversion\u0005count\bcomparer\u0004\0\0\u0003<System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary+DictionaryNode\u0002\0\0\0\b\b\u001cSystem.Collections.IComparer\u0002\0\0\0\t\u0003\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\n\u0005\u0003\0\0\0<System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary+DictionaryNode\u0003\0\0\0\u0003key\u0005value\u0004next\u0002\u0002\u0004<System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary+DictionaryNode\u0002\0\0\0\u0002\0\0\0\u0006\u0004\0\0\0\u00040001\u0006\u0005\0\0\0\u0004Text\t\u0006\0\0\0\f\a\0\0\0QSystem.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\u0001\u0006\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\b\0\0\0\n0001Center\t\t\0\0\0\t\n\0\0\0\u0005\t\0\0\0\u0015System.Drawing.PointF\u0002\0\0\0\u0001x\u0001y\0\0\v\v\a\0\0\0u\u001eÔ¿éÉÑÀ\u0001\n\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\v\0\0\0\r0001Expansion\t\f\0\0\0\t\r\0\0\0\u0005\f\0\0\0\u0014System.Drawing.SizeF\u0002\0\0\0\u0005width\u0006height\0\0\v\v\a\0\0\0e€Y@TžK?\u0001\r\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\u000e\0\0\0\t0001Color\t\u000f\0\0\0\t\u0010\0\0\0\u0005\u000f\0\0\0\u0014System.Drawing.Color\u0004\0\0\0\u0004name\u0005value\nknownColor\u0005state\u0001\0\0\0\t\a\a\a\0\0\0\n \0\0ÿ\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0002\0\u0001\u0010\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\u0011\0\0\0\b0001Text\u0006\u0012\0\0\0\u001bPARTIAL RELEASE IN  09/2573\t\u0013\0\0\0\u0001\u0013\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\u0014\0\0\0\b0001Font\t\u0015\0\0\0\t\u0016\0\0\0\u0005\u0015\0\0\0\u0013System.Drawing.Font\u0004\0\0\0\u0004Name\u0004Size\u0005Style\u0004Unit\u0001\0\u0004\u0004\v\u0018System.Drawing.FontStyle\a\0\0\0\u001bSystem.Drawing.GraphicsUnit\a\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\u0006\u0017\0\0\0\u0014Microsoft Sans Serif\0\0\u001cA\u0005èÿÿÿ\u0018System.Drawing.FontStyle\u0001\0\0\0\avalue__\0\b\a\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\0\u0005çÿÿÿ\u001bSystem.Drawing.GraphicsUnit\u0001\0\0\0\avalue__\0\b\a\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0001\u0016\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\u001a\0\0\0\v0001Charset\b\b\u0001\0\0\0\t\u001b\0\0\0\u0001\u001b\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\u0006\u001c\0\0\0\u00130001TextOrientation\b\b\0\0\0\0\n\v"
```

So now it looks like i have a string of meta data:
name\u0005
System.Drawing.FontStyle\u0001\0\0\0\a
etc etc

My question is how do i convert what appears to be name value pairs into something readable?

I am expecting a string such as

"Satisified on 1/1/2016" with the other attributes applied as neccessary.

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the code that produces the string

```
        foreach (var item in guids)
        {

            string docGUID = item.DocGuid;
            string path = "C:\\TestAnnotations\\" + docGUID;

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            var rows = results.AsEnumerable().Where(rw => (string)rw["DocGUID"] == docGUID);
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(800, 800);
            int lastImagePos = 1;

            foreach (var annotation in rows)
            {

                string fileName = path + "\\" + docGUID + lastImagePos.ToString() + ".tif";
                byte[] buffer = (byte[])annotation["Annotations"];

                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Maybe show some code?

Comment: I could absolutely but in this instance its not really the code im stuck on, its the output (i edited my question to show the full output string which may help a little more) that seems to need one more conversion process to be fully readable.

Thats what i am stuck on. What kind of conversion is needed to make that output string fully readable.

Comment: I have no idea what that text is without seeing code. What format is that string in? You mention an image column. That means nothing. That's just raw binary data. The code that wrote it is what is important. From what you provided I can offer no assistance.

Comment: That byte array doesnt look like it is image data.  It has several NET type names in it.  Show the code to store the image as well - if it did not go in correctly it wont come out correct.

Comment: code added. i do not have the code that put the value in the column. The client was using an old program that doesn't do what they need fully and are trying to write a new program that better suits there needs but want to try to perserve all the work theyve all ready done

Comment: @Plutonix you are correct. the byte array converted to a string. That is what you see above, the conversion from byte array to a string. i assume that part of the process is correct because there are readable words there. it is taking that string and further converting it so the values are also readable that i am stuck on

Comment: Is it an actual `Image` column? or is that just describing what is stored there? The image column has been deprecated for many years now, is why I ask.  If it is something like VarBinary, you have to recreate the image from the bytes.

Comment: it is indeed an actual image column. i suspect they serialized some object into bytes then stored it there. I dont necessarily need to recreate the object but if you look, it appears there are name value pairs

TextOrientation\b\b\0\0\0\0\n\v

so if i could get the stuff following textorientation to "left-justified" as an example, id be golden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the bad characters and return just a string by running the value above through this code:

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                    {
                        char c = text[i];
                        byte b = (byte)c;
                        if (b < 32)
                            test += " ";
                        else
                            test += c;
                    }
```